# How to correctly recreate a kubeadm 1.15.0 cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've created a 1.15.0 single-node kubeadm on a fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Then I deleted the cluster and recreated it. But now I can't recreate it anymore (I get etcd preflight-check error):

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.15.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
```

The commands that I've used are:

```
   # created a single node
    sudo swapoff -a
    sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
    mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
    sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
    curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/calico.yaml -O
    kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
    kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
   # reseted a single node
    sudo kubeadm reset
    rm -fr .kube/
   # recreated a single node
    sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. Did you try removing `/var/lib/etcd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with version `1.15.0`. I often delete and recreate clusters. I noticed this bug when I upgraded `kubeadm` version to `1.15.0`. You can just delete the `/var/lib/etcd` directory and you are good to go.

You can find more about the bug here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1642

Comment: Yeah.. turns out this bug was reported by me XD. It seems to me deleting etcd folder is not the fix they are working on. The merged fix changes the behavior of the preflight-checks (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79331).