# Does Minikube run in a Ubuntu 19.10 virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube, vmware-workstation

I installed kubectl and minikube as shown on the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) on Ubuntu 19.10 running in VMWare Workstation. When I start minikube with --vm-driver=none (since I'm running on a virtual machine) I get this error:

```
minikube v1.6.2 on Ubuntu 19.10
  Selecting 'none' driver from user configuration (alternates: [])
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Using the running none "minikube" VM ...
  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '19.03.2' ...
     kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
  Launching Kubernetes ...

Error starting cluster: running cmd: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.17.0:$PATH kubeadm init phase certs all --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml": /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.17.0:$PATH kubeadm init phase certs all --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml": exit status 1
stdout:
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk

stderr:
W0110 13:53:06.531592    6051 common.go:77] your configuration file uses a deprecated API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1". Please use 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.
W0110 13:53:06.532094    6051 common.go:77] your configuration file uses a deprecated API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1". Please use 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.
W0110 13:53:06.533419    6051 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kube-proxy config - no validator is available
W0110 13:53:06.533440    6051 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kubelet config - no validator is available
error execution phase certs/apiserver-kubelet-client: [certs] certificate apiserver-kubelet-client not signed by CA certificate ca: crypto/rsa: verification error
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
❌  Problems detected in kube-addon-manager ["c7ccb7eb00cc"]:
    error: You must be logged in to the server (error when retrieving current configuration of:
    error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
    error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
❌  Problems detected in kube-apiserver ["c91043e54554"]:
    I0110 20:52:44.283421       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:47838: remote error: tls: bad certificate
    I0110 20:52:44.483603       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:47846: remote error: tls: bad certificate
    I0110 20:52:44.549909       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:47848: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Is this a problem with Ubuntu 19.10 which uses the version 5 kernel, or a result of running in a VM, and is there a fix for it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you run minikube just directly on your host and therefore run the kubernetes in the VM. This is tested and should work without issues.

Comment: Or [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/), given that it's ubuntu, or [k3s](https://github.com/rancher/k3s#readme), or [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind#readme), or almost anything that isn't minikube

Comment: Have you happened to see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541104/minikube-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-19-10)?

Answer (score 0):

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541104/minikube-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-19-10) VKR provided a detail explaination of how to make it work. I am posting his answer as a community wiki:

---

Okay, so I reproduced and got the same errors with minikube after upgrading it to 19.10.

How I initiated cluster on 19.04:

```
#Install kubectl
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x ./kubectl && sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

#Install minikube. Make sure to check for latest version
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/

#Install Docker
curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && chmod +x get-docker.sh
sh get-docker.sh
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER


export MINIKUBE_WANTUPDATENOTIFICATION=false
export MINIKUBE_WANTREPORTERRORPROMPT=false
export MINIKUBE_HOME=$HOME
export CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
sudo minikube start --vm-driver none
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube


vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.3
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.10
 Git commit:        a872fc2f86
 Built:             Tue Oct  8 01:00:44 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.3
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       a872fc2f86
  Built:            Tue Oct  8 00:59:17 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683


vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-cv8c5           1/1     Running   0          2m25s
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-gk725           1/1     Running   0          2m25s
kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          75s
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   0          75s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          98s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          88s
kube-system   kube-proxy-59jp9                   1/1     Running   0          2m25s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          82s
kube-system   storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          2m24s
```

After upgrading to 19.10 and clean minikube install:

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ kubectl get all -A
Error in configuration: 
* unable to read client-cert /root/.minikube/client.crt for minikube due to open /root/.minikube/client.crt: permission denied
* unable to read client-key /root/.minikube/client.key for minikube due to open /root/.minikube/client.key: permission denied
* unable to read certificate-authority /root/.minikube/ca.crt for minikube due to open /root/.minikube/ca.crt: permission denied
```

There are a lots of discussions stating you should use `root` for `none driver` since minikube runs the kubernetes system components directly on your machine...

[Running minikube as normal user](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1899)

[Can't start minikube-- permissions](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4349)

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/:

> Usage The none driver requires minikube to be run as root, until
>   [#3760](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3760) can be
>   addressed

However.. here is a small trick for you..

1) wipe everything

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ minikube stop
✋  Stopping "minikube" in none ...
  "minikube" stopped.
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ minikube delete
  Uninstalling Kubernetes v1.16.0 using kubeadm ...
  Deleting "minikube" in none ...
  The "minikube" cluster has been deleted.
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ rm -rf ~/.kube
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ rm -rf ~/.minikube
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/minikube
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo rm -rf /root/.minikube
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

2) Install minikube, export variables, check

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$   export MINIKUBE_WANTUPDATENOTIFICATION=false
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  export MINIKUBE_WANTREPORTERRORPROMPT=false
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  export MINIKUBE_HOME=$HOME
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  export CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$  sudo minikube start --vm-driver none

  minikube v1.4.0 on Ubuntu 19.10
  Running on localhost (CPUs=2, Memory=7458MB, Disk=9749MB) ...
ℹ️   OS release is Ubuntu 19.10
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 19.03.3 ...
    ▪ kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
  Downloading kubelet v1.16.0
  Downloading kubeadm v1.16.0
  Pulling images ...
  Launching Kubernetes ... 
  Configuring local host environment ...

⚠️  The 'none' driver provides limited isolation and may reduce system security and reliability.
⚠️  For more information, see:
  https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

⚠️  kubectl and minikube configuration will be stored in /root
⚠️  To use kubectl or minikube commands as your own user, you may need to relocate them. For example, to overwrite your own settings, run:

    ▪ sudo mv /root/.kube /root/.minikube $HOME
    ▪ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube

  This can also be done automatically by setting the env var CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
⌛  Waiting for: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

What I do next is copy everything from `/root/.kube` and `/root/.minikube` to `$HOME`, grant user permissions and finally edit `$HOME/.kube/config` specifying new path to certs (`$HOME/.minikube/` instead of `/root/.minikube/`). Right now it looks like

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ cat $KUBECONFIG
apiVersion: v1
...
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
...
    client-certificate: /root/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /root/.minikube/client.key
```

Lets do it :)

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo cp -r /root/.kube  /root/.minikube $HOME
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
sed 's/root/home\/vkr/g' $KUBECONFIG > tmp; mv tmp $KUBECONFIG
```

And finally result..

```
vkr@ubuntu-minikube:~$ kubectl get all -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-bt897           1/1     Running   0          81m
kube-system   pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-hkm5t           1/1     Running   0          81m
kube-system   pod/etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          80m
kube-system   pod/kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   0          80m
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          80m
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          80m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-wm52p                   1/1     Running   0          81m
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          80m
kube-system   pod/storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          81m

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  81m
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   81m

NAMESPACE     NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   1         1         1       1            1           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   81m

NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns   2/2     2            2           81m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-5644d7b6d9   2         2         2       81m
```

---

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work.

The following instructions should be valid for Debian / Ubuntu / Mint Linux distributions. Your experience may vary if using an RHEL / Arch / Other distribution or non desktop distro like Ubuntu server, or lightweight distros which may omit many expected tools.

**Install VirtualBox:**

Find your Linux distribution and download the `.deb` package, using a graphical installer here should be sufficient. If you use a package manager like `apt` to install from your terminal, you will likely get a fairly out of date version.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

After installing, check your installation to make sure it worked:

`VBoxManage —version`

As an alternative you can use (or maybe you have to use) KVM instead of VirtualBox. Here are some great instructions that can be found in this post:

https://computingforgeeks.com/install-kvm-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian-sles-arch/

**Install Kubectl**

In your terminal run the following:

`curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl`

`chmod +x ./kubectl`

`sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

**Check your Installation:**

`kubectl version`

See also official docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux

**Install Minikube**

In your terminal run the following:

`curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube`

`sudo install minikube /usr/local/bin`

**Check your installation:**

`minikube version`

**Start Minikube:**

`minikube start`

See also official docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/