# how to run "minikube start --vm-driver=none" at boot

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, minikube

I want to run `minikube start --vm-driver=none` at boot by service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=minikube
After=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStart=minikube start --vm-driver=none
ExecStop=minikube stop
User=${USER}
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

But it not works

```
xiaojie@xiaojie-ubuntu:~$ systemctl status minikube.service
? minikube.service - minikube
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minikube.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-04-21 14:32:32 JST; 21min ago
    Process: 11903 ExecStart=/usr/bin/minikube start --vm-driver=none (code=exited, status=65)
   Main PID: 11903 (code=exited, status=65)

 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting minikube...
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu minikube[11903]: * minikube v1.19.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu sudo[11914]:  xiaojie : a password is required ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COM>
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu minikube[11903]: * Using the none driver based on existing profile
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu minikube[11903]: * Exiting due to PROVIDER_NONE_NOT_FOUND: The 'none' provider was not>
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu systemd[1]: minikube.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=65/DATAERR
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu systemd[1]: minikube.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 4? 21 14:32:32 xiaojie-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start minikube.
```

What I have changed are these:

```
sudo mv /root/.kube /root/.minikube $HOME
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube
```

Comment: Did you have all requirements https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/ ?

Comment: @Malgorzata I can run minikube driectly, but I need to input password before `minikube start`. So I think this issue stop systemd from starting minikube

Comment: Can you instead of`--driver=none` consider using the newer `--driver=docker`, which does not require root access. Also have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541104/minikube-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-19-10/58557265#58557265  ?